# Does the Snowflake Query Optimiser respect CTEs?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

If I write a SQL statement that includes CTEs, will the query optimiser always retain those CTEs as discrete statements to be optimised individually or can it merge those CTEs with other parts of the overall SQL if it calculates the resulting SQL will be quicker to execute?

This question was triggered by a question another user asked. They were using a sequence generator in a CTE; when the CTE SQL was run in isolation it always produced 12 consecutive numbers, as expected. However, when run in the CTE as part of a much larger SQL statement it was missing numbers i.e. it wasn't producing consecutive values.

This is a known issue/behaviour with large datasets but as there were only 12 values it shouldn't have been a problem - but the fact that it was suggests that the CTE was not being run as written, with the 12 record resultset then joined to the other tables, but instead the query optimiser had re-written the overall query and had merged the CTE logic with other parts of the SQL statement and so was prodcuing a much larger dataset.

Comment: Use `explain` to see what Snowflake is likely to be running.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does not provide a lot of explanation of how it optimizes queries.

I can say that in general, there are two ways to handle CTEs:

- Materialize the CTE so it is run once and then the materialized version is read.
- Incorporate the CTE logic into the the rest of the query and optimize as part of the query.

I would actually expect Snowflake to do *both*, choosing the better execution plan, because it is a modern database that has learned from decades of optimization experience.  Either method might be better under some circumstances.

All that said, if the data returned by the code changes as you describe it, then there is a bug.  The point of optimization is not to change the semantics (meaning) of the code.  The point is to return the *same* results but using different underlying algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess its a bit of a grey area: the sequence generator's behaviour is known not to produce consecutive values for large data sets; therefore using it in any circumstances that require consecutive values is, presumably, a risk. Is writing SQL where it should work, and then the query optimiser re-writing it to produce SQL where you could reasonably expect it not to work, a bug or a coding gotcha?

Comment: @NickW . . . If you are actually using a `sequence`, then you might have issues because that has side effects.  If you are using a function such as `row_number()` then the code should be safe.

Comment: CTE's aren't an "order of operations" so to speak in Snowflake.  The optimizer leverages them to create a single execution profile.  I have seen crazy side-effects of CTE when thinking it would be executed in order of the CTE, and it not actually being.  SEQ() functions, for example, are whacky.